# Append javascript content inside gwt dialogBox

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have a js function that shows some content in a div. So I create this div in my html panel and when calling js function from my gwt code the function works fine...(JNSI)

The problem is when I want to show this content in a dialogBox. So what I do is this: I create the dialogBox using uibinder and I create a div inside as follows:

```
     <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="hmtl_panel">
         <div ui:field="show_to_this_div">
        </div>
     </g:HTMLPanel>
```

and in the js I use "document.getElementById('show_to_this_div')" as when the div was in the html panel...But nothing happens :-(!

Comment: errors? JavaScript code?

Comment: No errors... I had some errors but with the following I get no erros.. ` while(step4.isAttached()){ //step4 is the dialogBox alert(); } public static native void alert() /*-{ $wnd.sayHello(); // $wnd is a JSNI synonym for 'window' }-*/; js funtion in external file.... function sayHello() { var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({ element: document.getElementById('show_to_this_div'), action: '/UploadServlet' , debug: true }); `

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `$wnd.document`